# Attempting to remove extra “edges” from truncated icosahedron lead to excessively global consequences

Tags: faces, edges, geometry

I need a truncated icosahedron. Blender lets me do that with add -> mesh -> math function -> regular solid (assuming the extra plugin is installed.) So far so good. However, the mesh that is created does not use n-gons. This means that each hexagon or pentagon face is cut by an unusable edge approximately through the middle. These extra "lines" destroy the visual symmetry I need for the wireframe.

I have tried deleting the extra edges. This results in the in the removal of far more than just the offending edge. It blows a huge hole in the whole object. I have tried merging the two faces (which compose the pentagon or hexagon) into an n-gon. Somehow this again ends up doing far more than just merge the two parts of the face.

No matter what I try I get unintended effects that are far to global. I have also considered drawing fresh lines over only the desired edges. I cannot figure out how to do this either. I have also extracted the faces and edges with python, but those are too cumbersome to edit... and then what?

How do I get a nice clean geometric wire frame without distracting extra edges?

Answer (score 8):

**Edge Selection**

The connected faces to edges of interest lie in the same plane. The edge angle is the angle between the normals of the two.

Can select all edges of interest by selecting one edge in edge selection mode, then in menu *Select > Select Similar > Face Angle*

[image]

then <kbd>X</kbd> Dissolve edges.
This is same behaviour as limited dissolve delimiting by Normal

**Limited Dissolve.**

[image]

Select all, and hit <kbd>X</kbd> choose limited dissolve. The use normal to delimit, *ie* the angular difference between the two faces (or less).

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm looking for! Thanks for the animated example.  I'm using Blender 2.91.2 When I Select -> Select Similar  I get a menu that has 5 submenus that read: Normal, Amount of Adjacent Faces, Vertex Groups, Amount of Connected edges.  This looks different from your animation. I suspect this is because I'm not "selecting one" correctly.   Please clarify.

Comment: I was not able to duplicate the selection process. However I was able to select regions and the use the limited dissolve to remove the extra faces.  Thanks for you help.  I'm past that roadblock.